# Two rtorrent processes running. Normal?

Tags: debian, rtorrent, beaglebone

I noticed when I ssh'ed into my beaglebone black that I got two rtorrent processes running.

[image]

is this something rtorrent does per default or have I messed up somewhere along the line? What could cause this and is this something I can fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use htop, which shows threads as separate processes. To be sure, check with `ps aux| grep rtorrent` or in htop use `H` key to show/hide user threads.

So it is normal what you see in htop.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Did a ps aux | grep rtorrent and got this https://i.imgur.com/BTPVEOo.png 
Take that both the screen process and the rtorrent running inside is the same? That last entry, what is that? Sorry for asking but I'm kinda new to this thing.

Comment: the first process is screen with its command line (it was run like that with rtorrent and so on), second process is rtorrent, and the third is the process of grep you just run :)